# Biophysically, how to change from a tonically firing neuron to an occasionally firing one?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, biophysics, neuron

In terms of membrane properties, size and neuronal biophysics (assuming no change in incoming excitation), how can a tonically firing neuron become (say during development) an occasionally bursting neuron?

Any references would be appreciated.